# Spring Integration DSL: How do I delete a list of JPA entities?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a bunch of JPA Entities that I retrieve like this:

```
.handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(myEntityManagerFactory).namedQuery(readQuery))
.transform(/* remove some of the entities from the message, leaving only the ones I want to delete */)
```

And now I would like to delete some of them. What is the best way to do this ? I'm thinking there must be some simple way to do it with a very simple or possibly even no explicit jpaQuery() at all ?

I'm imagining something like this:

```
.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(myEntityManagerFactory)
    .jpaQuery("delete from MyTable m where m in :items")
    .parameter("items", ...(?)... )
```

or like this:

```
.handle(Jpa.deletingGateway(myEntityManagerFactory))
```

What's the right way to do this with the Spring Integration DSL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(entityManagerFactory).persistMode(PersistMode.DELETE))
```

Although it works only for a single entity. So, consider to have your integration flow like this:

```
.handle(Jpa.retrievingGateway(myEntityManagerFactory).namedQuery(readQuery))
.transform(/* remove some of the entities from the message, leaving only the ones I want to delete */)
.split()
.handle(Jpa.updatingGateway(entityManagerFactory).persistMode(PersistMode.DELETE))
```

I mean add a splitter before JPA gateway. Of course if your `.transform()` returns the list.

I think we may make it more convenient for use-cases like yours if the payload of the message is an `Iterable`. There is already a `JpaOperations.deleteInBatch()`. So, the `JpaExecutor.executeOutboundJpaOperationOnPersistentMode()` could be improved in its branch:

```
case DELETE:
            this.jpaOperations.delete(payload);
            if (this.flush) {
                this.jpaOperations.flush();
            }
            return payload;
```

Feel free to raise a GH issue and we will revise it eventually!

Comment: Thanks for this ! I'll try to add this suggestion as a GH issue in the near future. And in the mean time I'm thinking I might just try making it work using IDs and a namedQuery like "delete from MyTable m where m.id in :ids" and pass a List of IDs to the JPA update operation.

Comment: Then your transformer would need to return the list of those ids

Comment: I raised the GH issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3614